# Android Studio (on Windows) send false gps coordinates to real device

Tags: android, android-studio, gps, coordinates, ddms

I want to test an Android application that works with gps coordinates on a real device.
I use Android Studio so I tried to use DDMS to send spoofed location to the device but i discovered that the function is now transferred to the android emulator so i cannot use it on a real device.

So, how can I send spoofed coordinates to my device to test the app? Has anyone faced the same issue? Thank you.